# Take an input file name and copy it but with a different file extension

Tags: c, file-rename

I'm trying to write a C program that takes an input file name, and outputs a file with the same name but a different extension. For example, it would take in a file example.in and output example.out.

I'm currently trying:

```
char *fname = argv[2];
char *fout = fname;
```

but I don't know how to proceed and change the extension of the file.

Comment: Time to brush up on the [C string library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte)

Comment: Probably want to look at `strrchr()` to locate the last `'.'` in the orignal filename. While `argv` is required to be mutable, it's probably better if you copy the original to a new buffer (e.g. `#include <limits.h>` and `char fout[PATH_MAX];` and `strcpy (fout, fname);` before you modify the contents of `fout` (that way the original is preserved in your argument vector as pointed to by `fname`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [strrchr](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strrchr).

From the man page:

```
The strrchr() function returns a pointer to the last occurrence of the
character c in the string s.
```

This will allow you to identify where your "." is. From there, you can copy the beginning of the string to a new memory area, and [strcat](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) the ending on.

Comment: `rindex` is not part of the C-standard (though it is functionally equivalent to `strrchr()`) See the note in the man page for `rindex` "*4.3BSD*; marked as *LEGACY* in *POSIX.1-2001*. *POSIX.1-2008* **removes** the specifications of `index()` and `rindex()`, recommending `strchr(3)` and `strrchr(3)` instead."